How do I solve the non normality of VAR model's residuals?
As the title said I'm trying to do a VAR model with these variables: FDI, GDP, Real effective exchange rate, volatility of exchange rate, percentage of school enrollment). While all these variables are non-stationary in level, they all are at I(1) at least with the ADF test at lag 1 and 2 (some are non stationary at lag 3).
So I decided to do a VAR since they have the same level of integration. The model is stable and there is no sign of autocorrelation BUT using the sktest in Stata I can see that the residuals are far from a normal distribution :

I've tried  'log'in the variables but no changes.
PS: I need the residuals to be normally distributed because my uni doesn't accept the model unless it is the case (sounds odd but it is what it is) plus I'm trying to do an IRF and it would be simpler with the residuals being normal.

I didn't know it was any university's policy to insist on normal residuals. Perhaps you mean your supervisor, advisor or whatever else they're called. More seriously, residuals that are symmetric and unimodal to a good approximation look good to me!

Incidental detail: Change the units of your data by e.g. dividing by 1 million. Then your residuals and density estimates would take on more civilised magnitudes. In Stata you should also insist on yla(, ang(h)) to get horizontal labels on the $y$ axis at each tick.

yes I meant my supervisor (sorry for the mixed up) and thanks I fixed the graph in my work. So there shouldn't be any incidence with the IRF then ? To be honest I'm more afraid of being criticized on using a faulty model just because the residuals aren't normal

I can't go beyond saying that your residuals don't seem unusual or problematic in my experience. Minor departures from normality are often flagged by significance tests in this territory. I (we) can't approve or disapprove of a model that I (we) can't see. That would require detailed discussion of your goals, your data, your model choices and your results. How far that's your concern and how far your supervisor can or will advise is between the two of you. If that seems obvious, good!

Ok great thank you for your advice :)
